# Get an Arraylist from an inner class

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-asynctask

I am seeking help so that I may get an `ArrayList<String>` in an alternate class. As you can see in the following code I have inner and outer classes. Both work as expected and I am both able to insert values and fetch details from my online database using php scripts (I have commented out these details for code clarity as it was taking up a lot of space).

```
public class ServerRequests {

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "// my url domain";

public ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();


public ServerRequests(Context context)
{
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");

}


public void storeDataInBackground(MultiChallenge multiChallenge)
{
    progressDialog.show();
    new StoreDataAsyncTask(multiChallenge).execute();

}

public class StoreDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void , Void , Void>
{
    MultiChallenge multiChallenge;


    public StoreDataAsyncTask(MultiChallenge multiChallenge)
    {
        this.multiChallenge = multiChallenge;

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // where I insert values...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Log.d("ServerRequests", "Post execute");
    }

}

public ArrayList<String> fetchDataInBackground() {
    progressDialog.show();
    new FetchDataAsyncTask().execute();

    return list1;
}

public class FetchDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>>
{
    public FetchDataAsyncTask()
    {

    }

    String text = "";

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

         InputStream is1;

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(// my url domain+ "// php script");

        try {

            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
            is1 = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader reader;

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                text += line + "\n";
            }
            is1.close();


            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(text);

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                Log.d("GetNames", data.getString(i));
                JSONObject jsonData = data.getJSONObject(i);
                list1.add( // I successfully add details to list1 here, I have commented it out for code clarity);

            }

            for (int iterate = 0; iterate < list1.size(); iterate++) {
                Log.d("list1", list1.get(iterate));
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        return list1;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> myList) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(myList);

    }
}
```

}

Now that I successfully add to the `list1` (I can tell values are added to it because of the for loop with the int iterate), I now need to send it to another class whereby I will put items in a `listview`. This is my code in the class in which I want to display the details of the `ArrayList` I get from `ServerRequests`:

```
ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests(DisplayInfo.this);

            ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
            myList = serverRequests.fetchDataInBackground();

            for (int iterate = 0; iterate < myList.size(); iterate++) {
                Log.d("Display", myList.get(iterate));
```

However the above for loop is never called, indicating that `myList` is never given the details that `list1` manages to get in the `doInBackground` method of class `FetchDataAsync`.

Please note I did spend a number of hours attempting a variety of my own ideas and answers derived from SO before asking this question. Thank you all in advance of your help.

Comment: It could very well be getting the data correctly, but since it's asynchronous, the loop is getting called before it's completed. You should run the loop in the `onPostExecute` of your async task

Comment: While I accept that it would make for a more reliable implementation to put it into the onPostExecute method, it was still confirmed that all the data was being placed in the list1 ArrayList since I was able to confirm this by using Logcat. I appreciate your help though and intend to implement your advice. For your reference, I was able to implement Varsha's answer and it works successfully. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onPostExecute method call a function in the calling class

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> myList) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(myList);
    MainActivity.sendStrings(myList);

}
```

In the calling function implement a method:

```
public static void sendStrings(ArrayList<String> strings)
{
  //Add for loop here
}
```

Alternatively you can also use interfaces. Call the interface in onPostExecute and implement the interface in the calling class

Comment: This was a very insightful answer as it provided another way of looking at the problem (implementing a static field instead in the DisplayInfo class). For reference to help others I implemented the first proposal that Varsha put forward, which does indeed yield the populated ArrayList I needed. Thank you very much indeed Varsha.

Comment: No Problem. Glad it helped you out :-)